# how to set a condition where the numbers are not less than 0 and not negative

Tags: javascript, html

for examples buy a product then he has a coin 200 then the price of the item reaches 250 then when he tries to buy then the price item does not meet the money he has a message that will appear that your money is not enough

Comment: `if (availableCoins >= itemPrice) { /* buy */ }`?

Comment: See [How much research is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). You are allowed to search the internet for programming tutorials first and learn a bit before asking a basic question.

Answer (score 1):

Please always post your code in future to be able to help you properly.

What you are looking for is roughly something like this:

```
let yourCoins = 200;
let itemPrice = 250;

if (yourCoins < itemPrice) {
    /* your message */
}
```